# Find centroid in image region

Tags: matlab, centroid

I have a set of matrixes with a number of blobs (this changes from matrix to matrix), and I'm looking for a way to find the center of mass of the blobs. To do so I use `regionprops` with the `Centroid` option.

```
B = bwlabel(A);
stat = regionprops(B,'Centroid');

number_centers = numel(stat);
coord_centers = zeros(number_centers,2);
xy_cylinder = zeros(number_centers,2);
for x = 1: number_centers
   coord_centers(x,1) = stat(x).Centroid(1);   % Angle
   coord_centers(x,2) = stat(x).Centroid(2);   % Radius
end
```

If I plot the matrix with the centroids superimposed (code below), I noticed that they slightly offset (they are on the corner of the pixel where the centroid is). Do you think I'm right? And do you know why is that?

```
axis equal;
pcolor(A), colorbar, hold on;
xlabel('Angle'); ylabel('Radius');
for x = 1: numel(stat)
    plot(stat(x).Centroid(1),stat(x).Centroid(2),'r+');
end
```

[image]

Comment: I think this is more of a visualisation problem. E.g. when you have a line which is 3 pixels long, `A(4,6:8)=1`, then the centroid should be at `(4,7)`, which is exactly what Matlab calculates. When visualizing this, the same effect as you describe happens - the centroid is not in the middle of the line, because the area between `(4,6)` and  `(5,9)` marked.

Comment: Thanks! So to correctly visualise the position of the centroid, is it fine if I add half a pixel to its x and y coordinate? For the image above, the centroids are located in (11, 19) and (16.9, 17.1).

Comment: That should work fine for the visualization, but for further calculations you should still use the calculated centroids.